# QueryDSL build a query with subclass

Tags: java, jpql, querydsl

I am building a query in QueryDSL. I have entity and sub class entity having same column. I wanna use same query to both entity using only single JPAQuery.

here is my entity.

```
@Entity
public class Region {

  @Id
  private Integer id;

}

@Entity
public class RegionTemp extends Region {}
```

queryer

```
@Component
public class RegionQueryer {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager mysqlEntityManager;

    QRegion qRegion = QRegion.region; // ???

    public Integer loadLastId() {

        return new JPAQueryFactory(mysqlEntityManager)
                .select(qRegion.id)
                .from(qRegion)
                .orderBy(qRegion.id.desc()).fetchFirst();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My code. this sample. if you want to using single query. use simple Repository. it take easy find, delete, save. you search JPA Tutorial.

```
@Override
public List<CompanyInformaion> findCompanyInformationList(String language, Association association) {
    QCompanyInformaion qCompanyInformaion = QCompanyInformaion.companyInformaion;
    QCompany qCompany = QCompany.company;

    EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    JPAQuery jpaQuery = new JPAQuery(em);

    List<CompanyInformaion> infos = jpaQuery.from(qCompanyInformaion)
            .where(qCompanyInformaion.language.eq(language)
                    .and(qCompanyInformaion.company.in(new JPASubQuery().from(qCompany)
                            .where(qCompany.association.eq(association)).list(qCompany))))
            .orderBy(qCompanyInformaion.companyName.asc()).list(qCompanyInformaion);

    return infos;
}
```